# Undefined component type Bootsfaces Navbar

Tags: bootsfaces

I have the following problem with running web application based on bootsfaces on server hosted by university. Application code is correct, i use same libraries and tomEE to develop it on my pc and it runs correctly, but on server it doesn't want to run correctly. Error code on pastebin https://pastebin.com/M1fieBzf
Thanks for any guidance.

```
Undefined component type net.bootsfaces.component.navBar.NavBar
```

[server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cs9p.png)

Comment: That's a weird bug. The server info indicates that your university uses a Tomcat, but that might just be a TomEE in disguise. I'm almost sure that's not the problem, but just to be sure, please double-check this. Because you need to add a couple of jar files to the Tomcat war which aren't needed by the TomEE war.

Comment: On the other hand, that might be the answer: if you're deploying to TomEE, make sure you don't add jar files which are already part of the application server. In particular, don't include neither Mojarra nor MyFaces with the *.war file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the JSF jars (i.e. Mojarra or MyFaces) in your war file? If so, omit them. If you're using Maven, that's achieved by setting the dependency scope to `provided`. Otherwise, the libraries are loaded twice, which leads to all kinds of errors.

BTW, do you know which application server your university uses?